# How to be notified about ABPersonSortOrdering changes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, abaddressbook

How to be notified when the user changes Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Sort Order (or Display Order)?

I want to reload a table of contacts in my app when the user makes such a change.